# Allow regular user to use mount without SUDO or FSTAB

Tags: linux, mount, sudo, cifs

Our desktop workstations are linux.

Each user uses Active Directory to authenticate. Mount does not automatically use the users PAM credentials to authenticate against a remote mount point - you must use either a credentials file or type in your username/domain/password on the command line.

Each user has encrypted home directories and they mount their remote mount points to a directory structure under their home directory.

Each user has different access rights on the domain and they want to keep their credentials file in their local plasma-vault.

Unfortunately, even when the plasma-vault is open, the moment they use sudo to run mount, the sudo process runs as root, who can not see the contents of the vault.

So, I need to have the users be able to run `mount`, under their own home directory, without the need for `/etc/fstab` via `sudo`.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you investigated `fuse`  it creates sshfs mounts without using root, perhap it can also do CIFS mounts?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` is not only used for elevating a user to full root access.

Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow your uses to use `mount` and `umount`.  Use the `sudo visudo` to ensure the file permissions are kept the same.

The edit would include a line such as this:

`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /usr/bin/umount`

For more options, see the [sudoers manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html).

Comment: And now your users have unfetterd root access to the system. Wonderful. This adds nothing over just giving users full `sudo`.

Comment: doesn't seem to work on centos 7, `mount: only root can use "--options" option`

Comment: Could the safety of this be improved by allowing users to mount only under a specific mount point, e.g., `/mnt/unsafe-user-mounts`?